# Question on Definition of Integrability

Tags: integration

The definition of integrability, as I understand it, is that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there exists a partition $P$ such that the difference between lower and upper Darboux sums of $f$ with respect to this parition is within $\epsilon$.

With this said, many proofs involve exploiting the fact that we could write $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there is a partition $P$ such that the upper and lower sums are within $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Taking the sum eventually yields a result that is within $\epsilon$.

My question is: how can we reason that the difference is $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$? Is the argument that, since $\epsilon$ is any real number greater than $0$, surely dividing it by $2$ would yield another number greater than $0$, which is effectively our new $\epsilon$? I don't know if I'm quite following such  logic, because we nonetheless end up with $\epsilon$ in the end. It seems like the $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is a finer point than $\epsilon$, though our lower bound at $0$ probably implies we can find an infinite number of irrational numbers $> 0$ such that this is true.

Comment: $\epsilon/2$ is often used, mainly because we want that $\epsilon$ nice, plain, and unadorned at the end of our proof. Sometimes you'll see folks use $\epsilon/3$, because they have three pieces they need to add up. If you can make something as small as you want, you can make it smaller than $\epsilon/2$ or $\epsilon/3$.

Comment: Excellent -- so the idea is, we can make $\epsilon$ any positive real number we want, and so dividing it by $2$ (even if we wanted to rename it, I suppose) is likewise acceptable? By this same notion, though, wouldn't the eventual sum that ends in $< \epsilon$ be relatively larger than that initial difference? I suppose, even if that is the case, it likely wouldn't matter, as it would be sufficient to write the proof.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. It would, but that isn't the inequality you usually need to prove. 3. Right!

Comment: You're very welcome!